# Why isn't bash logical OR operator working in GNU makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, make

I have the following GNU make Makefile

---

```
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m += liason.o

default:
        bash -c '[ "$(lsmod|grep liason)" == "" ] || rmmod liason'
        make -C /src M=$(PWD) modules
```

---

I invoke the makefile; it shows this among the output:

```
bash -c '[ "" == "" ] ||  rmmod liason'
```

Thus, `rmmod` isn't executed.

*However:*

Module "liason" *is* installed.
It even shows up when I execute the following from cmdline.

```
$ lsmod|grep liason
liason                 16384  0
```

Therefore, empty quotes for the same `lsmod|grep` in the makefile output doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` is being processed by Make; `$(lsmod|grep liason)` produces an empty string, the commands aren’t actually executed. To pass the expression on to the shell instead, you need to double the `$`:

```
bash -c '[ "$$(lsmod|grep liason)" == "" ] || rmmod liason'
```

You can simplify this as follows:

```
if lsmod | grep -q liason; then rmmod liason; fi
```

This ensures that any error when removing the module will stop the build.

Comment: The simplified version is producing rather inscrutable error, "make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1"

Comment: appending "; true" to each line to throw away the exit status of 1 from the lsmod | grep -q works.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! Appending `; true` means that any `rmmod` error will be ignored, see the updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: In your orig answer `lsmod | grep -q liason && rmmod liason`, it's grep's error that must be ignored, since rmmod is conditionally executed to avoid error. When rmmod is bypassed in cases where grep fails, grep is the last command executed and leaves its exit status representative of the compound/conditional command tested by make. `lsmod | grep -q liason && rmmod; true` ensures make sees success. I tested your 2nd answer and it *does* work. Apparently wrapping the command in an `if/then` swallows the exit status of the conditional clause. Your form is less arcane thus more maintainable. Torn.

Comment: My point is that when `rmmod` is supposed to be executed, if the removal fails, it will exit with a non-zero exit code. Adding `; true` will ignore that, as well as the exit code from `grep` when `rmmod` *isn’t* supposed to be run. Ignoring `grep` is fine because it’s expected; ignoring `rmmod` isn’t. Wrapping `grep` in `if` handles the `grep` error without ignoring `rmmod`’s potential errors.

Comment: I appreciate your help immensely. Your final answer is the best one because it is the clearest, simplest and language-appropriate way to do it, and that should be the end of it :-); wasn't trying to make a Federal case or quibble about semantics, just wanted to leave a comment I might want to see in the future if I ever wanted to nerd out on some specifics.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I only thought it worth clarifying my reasoning.